# How to solve character encoding issue with Emacs, mathematica.el, and Mathematica 10?

Tags: emacs, wolfram-mathematica, elisp

I am successfully using mathematica.el in Emacs with Mathematica 10. However, I have some kind of issue with character encoding whereby when I call mathematica-execute on a Mathematica expression the result prints lots of ^M characters to the output (I am running all processes on OS X Mavericks). I initially made sure that the $CharacterEncoding in Mathematica matched the file and process encoding of Emacs for the buffers being used as best I could: utf-8. There could still be an issue there, but that route didn't yield a solution. Next I thought, why not just create my own function that calls mathematica-execute and then removes the ^M characters from the resulting output. Here is the relevant code:

```
(defun delete-to-out ()
     (next-line)
     (set-mark-command nil)
     (search-forward "]=")
     (previous-line)
     (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))

(defun remove-^M ()
  "Get rid of ^M characters"
  (interactive)
  (message "remove-^M called!")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\r" nil t)
      (replace-match ""))))

(defun my-mathematica-execute (arg)
  "Call mathematica-execute and then clean out the ^M characters
  it inserts by calling remove-^M"
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (mathematica-execute arg)
    (remove-^M)
    ;; (delete-to-out)
    ))

;;; Define some mathematica mode keyboard bindings
(if mathematica-mode-map
    (progn
      (define-key mathematica-mode-map [remap mathematica-execute]
        'my-mathematica-execute)
      (define-key mathematica-mode-map (kbd "C-c m")
        'remove-^M)))
```

Calling my-mathematica-execute works, but isn't successful at removing the ^M characters. Calling remove-^M or delete-to-out work fine in isolation subsequently. It must be a synchronization issue or timing issue? Any help would be appreciated. Alternative solutions are certainly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The ^M indeed look like decoding issues, but it's not the character-encoding that's the problem but the EOL-encoding.  Both are specified together usually in Emacs, so you probably need to use `utf-8-dos` instead of `utf-8` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Stefan. I thought as you did, but found that wasn't it. Mathematica is using utf-8 as is my Emacs across all (as far I as I can tell) relevant contexts (that being said, this is Emacs and we have terminal, keyboard, file, process, and possibly other contexts to set encodings in).

Comment: I was able to find an appropriate place to hack in a function called mathematica-filter which gets set as the process filter for the mathematica process output. There I inserted a replace-regexp-in-string call to get rid of all \r characters. That works. Now I just will tweak things a bit: it currently echoes the input to output (along with the result) and I may not want that. Typically that is due to the underlying shell echoing (since Mathematica is executing in the shell, zsh). At least I have my entry point now where I can manipulate the ouput stream to my liking. ...

Comment: Hopefully someone will come along and tell me how to make Emacs and zsh work together to stop the echoing of input, but that is probably another question and I may pose it separately. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: I was able to get my desired outcome: no ^M characters and no input echoing by hacking on mathematica-filter in two places. For those interested, here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/analyticd/de40d724975627673928#file-gistfile1-diff) to the diffs.

Comment: The gist linked in the previous comment is not quite perfect. I'll update when I get it fully situated. I am too aggressively trimming the echoed input and it is removing some of the output, e.g., the numerator of a fraction. This is easy to fix.

Comment: My point (and still is) that the right way to remove those ^M is to change the coding-system (more specifically the process's output coding-system) with one that ends in `-dos`.